# jQuery "uniform" plugin code doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

So, I've never used jQuery before, but there is a script I want called Uniform, but I can't seem to get it to work. In the Safari debugger it is giving me 3 errors:

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (jquery.js, line 1)
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (jquery.uniform.js, line 1)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
    global code (index.php, line 8)
```

Here is the beginning of my index.php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PattersonCode.ca</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/incls/style.css">
<script src="incls/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="incls/jquery.uniform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $("select, input, a.button, button").uniform();
})
</script>
</head>
```

Solved it by using a full URL (http://pattersoncode.ca/incls/uniform.jquery.js)

Comment: Since it's saying it can't find `$`, it looks like jQuery isn't loaded. Is the browser's console reporting that it can't find `jquery.js`? Does `jquery.js` have jQuery in it?

Comment: It seems that your files have loaded - I wonder if they actually contain the JS source? I would open up jquery.js and check that it's not an HTML page which was accidentally downloaded :)

Comment: Like Sam said, it looks like jQuery isn't loaded up. Can you post the first few lines of jquery.js?

Comment: Just copied the random few first lines of jquery:

Comment: /*! jQuery v1.10.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery-1.10.2.min.map
*/
(function(e,t){var n,r,i=typeof t,o=e.location,a=e.document,s=a.documentElement,l=e.jQuery,u=e.$,c={},p=[],f="1.10.2",d=p.concat,h=p.push,g=p.slice,m=p.indexOf,y=c.toString,v=c.hasOwnProperty,b=f.trim,x=function(e,t){return new x.fn.init(e,t,r)}

Comment: I suspect the version of jQuery you are trying to use is incompatible with the Uniform plugin. Try using the Google CDN instead of your local copy and try v1.8.3 `<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you need to use the document.ready() block to make sure everything has loaded up before you execute the script? (shot in the dark here)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // code here
   $(function() {
     $("select, input, a.button, button").uniform();
   })
});
```

also from the uniform site:

```
<!-- Make sure your CSS file is listed before jQuery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="uniform.default.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.uniform.js"></script>
```

<strike>SO you might need Jquery 1.8</strike>

EDIT:

this works for me ...  Using both jQuery 1.8 and 1.10.1
I downloaded Uniform 2.1.1 and extracted it into the incls folder

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PattersonCode.ca</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="incls/themes/default/css/uniform.default.css" media="screen" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="incls/jquery.uniform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   // code here
   $(function() {
     $("select, input, a.button, button").uniform();
   })
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
<input type="text" value="banana" size="15" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (jquery.uniform.js, line 1)

Comment: I would use the CDN for the 1.8 version and then give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are jquery path is wrong or you don't have file in that folder..

i would like to suggest use jquery CDN with fallback code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='incls/jquery.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
}
</script>
<script src="incls/jquery.uniform.js"></script>
```

Comment: Now I get: [Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (jquery.uniform.js, line 1) and [Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("select, input, a.button, button").uniform()')
 (anonymous function) (index.php, line 9)
 c (jquery.min.js, line 4)
 fireWith (jquery.min.js, line 4)
 ready (jquery.min.js, line 4)
 q (jquery.min.js, line 4)